# Spectral gap for the Brownian motion with drift on a compact manifold

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, sp.spectral-theory

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary, $X$ a smooth vector field on $M$. Consider the Brownian motion $t\mapsto B_t$ on $M$ with drift $X$, so that its generator is $L=\Delta +X$. The associated semigroup $(P_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is defined by
$$ P_tf:x\mapsto \mathbb E_x[f(B_t)] $$
on $\mathcal C = \mathcal C(M,\mathbb R)$, and its dual operator $P^*_t$, defined on $\mathcal C^*$, acts on measures as $ (P^*_t\mu)(f) = \mu(P_tf) $.

Restrict this operator to the space $ \mathcal C^*_0 $ of forms $ \phi\in\mathcal C^* $ such that $\phi(1) = 0$.

> Is it true that
>   $$ \|P^*_T\|_{\mathcal C^*_0\to\mathcal C^*_0}<1 $$
>   holds for some $T>0$ large enough?

If not, is there anything to say, e.g. in a decreasing order of hopes:

- Does $ \|P_T\|_{L^2\to L^2}<1 $ holds, where $ L^2 $ is considered with respect to the Riemannian volume?
- Does the generator $ L $, restricted to the space $L^2_0$ of zero mean square integrable functions, enjoy some spectral gap? Something along the lines of $ \mathrm{Re}\ \mathrm{Sp}(-L)>0 $?
- Is the spectrum of $ L $ discrete?

Because $X$ is $\Delta$-compact, the essential spectrum of $-L$, in the '$\lambda I + L$ is Fredholm' sense, is empty, but that's about what I know about it.

This may be a reference request, as I have found papers around the issue, but I was unable to answer any of the above points.

### Remarks

I'm looking for a spectral proof of ergodic properties (existence and uniqueness of an invariant measure, exponential mixing...), so a solution not relying on ergodic results would be nice, but anything is of interest.

In the case $X=0$, one can work in a basis of eigenvectors for $\Delta$, use the fact that $|P_tf|_{\mathcal C}$ is dominated by $|P_tf|_{L^2}+\cdots+|\Delta^nP_t|_{L^2}$ and the existence of a spectral gap $\lambda_1>0$ to show that for any $t\geq 1$ and $0<\mu<\lambda_1$,
$$ \|P_t\|_{\mathcal C_0\to\mathcal C_0} \leq C\mathbf e^{-\mu t}$$
for a well-chosen $C>0$. This, in some sense, gives hopes regarding the above considerations.

I also know that some results are known when $X = \nabla f $, but it seems not to be the case I'm interested in.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Have you made any progress on this question?

Comment: @S.Surace Thank you for your interest! The short answer is not really. What I know now is that $L$ has discrete spectrum, and its eigenvalues have bounded real part (I think $\Re\lambda\leq |\mathrm{div}X|_\infty/2$). This follows from the fact that $L-\lambda I$ has a compact inverse for $\lambda$ as described. Depending on how much you want to assume about it, it is not too difficult.

Comment: Setting $A(u,v)=-\Re\langle Lu-\lambda u,v\rangle$ as a bilinear form on $H^1$, we see that $A$ is continuous coercive for appropriate $\lambda$ (one can show $A(u,v)=\|\nabla u\|^2+\int|u|^2(\Re\lambda+\mathrm{div}(X)/2)$). Using Lax-Milgram, we know that $L-\lambda I$ is invertible from $H^1$ to $H^{-1}$. With a bit of work we see that the domain of $L$ is $H^2$ and $L-\lambda I$ is invertible from $H^2$ to $L^2$. This shows that the spectral values have small real part. The fact that the spectrum is discrete comes from the fact that the inverse is compact (it has image in $H^2$).

Comment: Also it is clear from probabilistic arguments that the result is true, but the argument I know uses no spectral analysis whatsoever, so I was hoping for an alternative proof. If you are interested in this proof, you can send me an email.